# Rails 5.2 tinymce_rails gem Not Showing Multiple Toolbars

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce

I have the TinyMCE gem installed on rails and it is showing the "Tools" toolbar and the code icon, but I can't get it to display more than that.

Because some toolbars are showing up, I know the gem is properly installed, but I can't get it to show other toolbars.

The text area is called like this:

```
    <%= f.text_area :notes, class: "tinymce", rows: 20, style: "width: 100%" %>
```

And the on-page script is like this:

```
  <%= tinymce_assets %>
  <%= tinymce plugins: ["wordcount", "code", "anchor", "casechange", "codesample", "hr", "link", "preview"] %>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea.tinymce",  // change this value according to your HTML
        plugins: "code image link",
        toolbar: "styleselect | bold italic | code codeformat | undo redo",
        menubar: "tools"
      });
    });
  </script>
```

I have these in `application.js`:

```
//= require tinymce
//= require tinymce-jquery
```

However, I've tried it without `tinymce-jquery` as well, to no avail.

I have the following in `config/tinymce.yml`:

```
toolbar:
  - styleselect | bold italic code codeformat | undo redo
  - image | link | code | preview
plugins:
  - image
  - link
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?  I need more than just the code editor!

Comment: You are initializing TinyMCE twice - first with rails gem helper 

    <%= tinymce plugins: ["wordcount", "code", "anchor", "casechange", "codesample", "hr", "link", "preview"] %>


and then in JS init. Try to remove one of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are limiting you toolbar to display icons

```
//current code 
toolbar: "styleselect | bold italic | code codeformat | undo redo",

//add more items
toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image jbimages",
```

Below the is code with all the possible features and you can also [view it here](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/demo/full-featured/)

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea#full-featured',
  plugins: 'print preview powerpaste casechange importcss tinydrive searchreplace autolink autosave save directionality advcode visualblocks visualchars fullscreen image link media mediaembed template codesample table charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor toc insertdatetime advlist lists checklist wordcount tinymcespellchecker a11ychecker imagetools textpattern noneditable help formatpainter permanentpen pageembed charmap tinycomments mentions quickbars linkchecker emoticons advtable',
  tinydrive_token_provider: 'URL_TO_YOUR_TOKEN_PROVIDER',
  tinydrive_dropbox_app_key: 'YOUR_DROPBOX_APP_KEY',
  tinydrive_google_drive_key: 'YOUR_GOOGLE_DRIVE_KEY',
  tinydrive_google_drive_client_id: 'YOUR_GOOGLE_DRIVE_CLIENT_ID',
  mobile: {
    plugins: 'print preview powerpaste casechange importcss tinydrive searchreplace autolink autosave save directionality advcode visualblocks visualchars fullscreen image link media mediaembed template codesample table charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor toc insertdatetime advlist lists checklist wordcount tinymcespellchecker a11ychecker textpattern noneditable help formatpainter pageembed charmap mentions quickbars linkchecker emoticons advtable'
  },
  menu: {
    tc: {
      title: 'TinyComments',
      items: 'addcomment showcomments deleteallconversations'
    }
  },
  menubar: 'file edit view insert format tools table tc help',
  toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic underline strikethrough | fontselect fontsizeselect formatselect | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent |  numlist bullist checklist | forecolor backcolor casechange permanentpen formatpainter removeformat | pagebreak | charmap emoticons | fullscreen  preview save print | insertfile image media pageembed template link anchor codesample | a11ycheck ltr rtl | showcomments addcomment',
  autosave_ask_before_unload: true,
  autosave_interval: "30s",
  autosave_prefix: "{path}{query}-{id}-",
  autosave_restore_when_empty: false,
  autosave_retention: "2m",
  image_advtab: true,
  content_css: [
    '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,400,400i',
    '//www.tiny.cloud/css/codepen.min.css'
  ],
  link_list: [
    { title: 'My page 1', value: 'http://www.tinymce.com' },
    { title: 'My page 2', value: 'http://www.moxiecode.com' }
  ],
  image_list: [
    { title: 'My page 1', value: 'http://www.tinymce.com' },
    { title: 'My page 2', value: 'http://www.moxiecode.com' }
  ],
  image_class_list: [
    { title: 'None', value: '' },
    { title: 'Some class', value: 'class-name' }
  ],
  importcss_append: true,
  height: 400,
  templates: [
        { title: 'New Table', description: 'creates a new table', content: '<div class="mceTmpl"><table width="98%%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><th scope="col"> </th><th scope="col"> </th></tr><tr><td> </td><td> </td></tr></table></div>' },
    { title: 'Starting my story', description: 'A cure for writers block', content: 'Once upon a time...' },
    { title: 'New list with dates', description: 'New List with dates', content: '<div class="mceTmpl"><span class="cdate">cdate</span><br /><span class="mdate">mdate</span><h2>My List</h2><ul><li></li><li></li></ul></div>' }
  ],
  template_cdate_format: '[Date Created (CDATE): %m/%d/%Y : %H:%M:%S]',
  template_mdate_format: '[Date Modified (MDATE): %m/%d/%Y : %H:%M:%S]',
  height: 600,
  image_caption: true,
  quickbars_selection_toolbar: 'bold italic | quicklink h2 h3 blockquote quickimage quicktable',
  noneditable_noneditable_class: "mceNonEditable",
  toolbar_drawer: 'sliding',
  spellchecker_dialog: true,
  spellchecker_whitelist: ['Ephox', 'Moxiecode'],
  tinycomments_mode: 'embedded',
  content_style: ".mymention{ color: gray; }",
  contextmenu: "link image imagetools table configurepermanentpen",
  /* 
  The following settings require more configuration than shown here.
  For information on configuring the mentions plugin, see:
  https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/mentions/.
  */
  mentions_selector: '.mymention',
  mentions_fetch: mentions_fetch,
  mentions_menu_hover: mentions_menu_hover,
  mentions_menu_complete: mentions_menu_complete,
  mentions_select: mentions_select,
 });
```

and as suggested by @VitauatsStocka, remove below code
`<%= tinymce plugins: ["wordcount", "code", "anchor", "casechange", "codesample", "hr", "link", "preview"] %>`.

Comment: Thanks!  Not only did this fix it, but it's a great compilation of all the options!